# Root Stack Exchange site URL doesn't open in app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I go from a web link to a Stack Exchange question or answer, the app correctly asks if I want to open the link in the app.

This doesn't work for the root site URLs though. Askubuntu.com opens in a browser, and each question in the list wants to open in the app. The same thing happens with patents.stackexchange.co.

Comment: If you visit the URL directly in Chrome (and I think the native browser works this way too), the intent isn't broadcast bringing the chooser up since you explicitly took the action of wanting to browse to that URL. But if you click on a Stack Exchange link, it works as expected by bringing up the chooser for patents.stackexchange.com and Ask Ubuntu for me.

Comment: I noticed this when reading a blog post about Ask Patents in Chrome. Navigating to the link to the site didn't bring up the chooser.

Answer (score 4):

Well, from what I can see this is not possible to do in Android at the moment, so I'm sad to say I don't think this bug will be resolved.

What I *can* do is make it so the app is opened to the questions list page when you click on a link to one of the websites from another website, but it doesn't also trigger when you manually type in "stackoverflow.com" or another website name manually into the URL box in a browser, which I think makes this somewhat moot.

However, if the community would like the feature to work with the big caveat mentioned, I'll go ahead and do it, it doesn't take long to implement but I do think that the way it doesn't work is the biggest possible use case for it.

Edit:

As of version 0.1.52 coming out later tonight the application will navigate you over to the "list of questions" page in the app if you click on a Stack Exchange website's URL in your browser.

Comment: Your solution sounds adequate to me.